# Android - Adding Calendar event thru an Intent - Availability value doesn't get updated

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I am creating a calendar event using startActivity by passing an intent. The calendar event gets created successfully and am also able to see all the information I pass except for the availability info. Whatever I send, the availability stays as Busy. Am I doing something wrong. My code is below.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
  intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
  intent.putExtra("beginTime", dtstart);
  intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
  intent.putExtra("endTime", dtend);
  intent.putExtra("title", "blah blah");
  intent.putExtra("description", "blah blah and more blah");
  intent.putExtra("availability", 1);
  ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 4.0 or above the CalendarContract can be used as below which updates the availability also correctly....

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Test Title")
    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Description")
    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Location")
    **.putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)**
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "test1@example.com,test2@example.com");
     startActivity(intent);
```